# SnowFlake stored procedure to delete a row from a table based on a condition

Tags: javascript, sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm deleting a row from a table based on the where condition, but I don't understand where I'm going wrong

I have a table TABLE1 as follows

```
-------------------------------
|  DB |  SC  |  TB  | COLUMNS |
-------------------------------
| DB1 |  SC1 |  TB1 |   COL1  |
| DB2 |  SC2 |  TB2 |   COL2  | <-- Delete this row
| DB3 |  SC3 |  TB3 |   COL3  |
-------------------------------
```

Here is my stored procedure

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DEL(COL VARCHAR) // taking column name as parameter to delete that row
        RETURNS string
        LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
        AS
        $$
            var str = '';
            var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "DELETE FROM DATA_QUALIT WHERE COLUMNS = +COL+";"});
            stmt.execute(); 
            return str;     
        $$;

    CALL DEL('COL2');  //Calling the procedure
```

But, I'm getting an error

```
Execution error in store procedure DEL: SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 40 invalid identifier 'COL2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are simply missing the single quotes around the value:

```
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "DELETE FROM DATA_QUALIT WHERE COLUMNS = '" + COL +"';"});
```